# How should I change this declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, resize

I have been given a header with the following declaration:

```
//The index of 1 is used to make sure this is an array.
MyObject objs[1];
```

However, I need to make this array dynamically sized one the program is started. I would think I should just declare it as MyObject *objs;, but I figure if the original programmer declared it this way, there is some reason for it.

Is there anyway I can dynamically resize this? Or should I just change it to a pointer and then malloc() it?

Could I use some the new keyword somehow to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct. If you want to dynamically instantiate its size you need to use a pointer.

(Since you're using C++ why not use the **new** operator instead of *malloc*?)

```
MyObject* objs = new MyObject[size];
```

Comment: oh, I think you're correct. I've gotten so used to C# it's tainted my C++ :)

Answer (score 16):

Use an [STL vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<MyObject> objs(size);
```

A vector is a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_list) and is a part of the [Standard Template Library](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). It resizes automatically as you [push back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) objects into the array and can be accessed like a normal C array with the [`[]` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/). Also, `&objs[0]` is guaranteed to point to a contiguous sequence in memory -- unlike a [list](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html) -- if the container is not empty.

Comment: "&objs[0] is guaranteed to point to a contiguous sequence in memory" But please be warnd: that's only ok when you are sure your vector is not empty (using empty() method for instance). Otherwise it could lead to Undefined behavior.

Comment: if you know size in advance then Vector::reserve() would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> Or should I just change it to a
>   pointer and then malloc() it?

If you do that, how are constructors going to be called for the objects in on the malloc'd memory? I'll give you a hint - they won't be - you need to use a std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen an array used as a pointer inside a struct or union.  This was ages ago and was used to treat the len and first char of a string as a hash to improve the speed of string comparisons for a scripting language.

The code was similar to this:

```
union small_string {
   struct {
      char len;
      char buff[1];
   };
   short hash;
};
```

Then small_string was initialised using malloc, note the c cast is effectively a reinterpret_cast

```
small_string str = (small_string) malloc(len + 1);
strcpy(str.buff, val);
```

And to test for equality

```
int fast_str_equal(small_string str1, small_string str2)
{
   if (str1.hash == str2.hash)
      return strcmp(str1.buff, str2.buff) == 0;
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see this is not a very portable or safe style of c++.  But offered a great speed improvement for associative arrays indexed by short strings, which are the basis of most scripting languages.

I would probably avoid this style of c++ today.

Answer (score 1):

Is this at the end of a struct somewhere?

One trick I've seen is to declare a struct

```
struct foo {
/* optional stuff here */
int arr[1];
}
```

and malloc more memory than `sizeof (struct foo)` so that `arr` becomes a variable-sized array.

This was fairly commonly used in C programs back when I was hacking C, since variable-sized arrays were not available, and doing an additional allocation was considered too error-prone.

The right thing to do, in almost all cases, is to change the array to an STL vector.

Answer (score 0):

Using the STL is best if you want a dynamically sizing array, there are several options, one is [std::vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx). If you aren't bothered about inserting, you can also use std::list.

Comment: That doesn't solve his problem. If he can change it to a pointer, he has plenty of options for resizing it. realloc won't let him resize the array while using the current declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems - yes, you can do this change.
But check your code on sizeof( objs );

```
MyObj *arr1 = new MyObj[1];
MyObj arr2[1];

sizeof(arr1) != sizeof(arr2)
```

Maybe this fact used somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

That comment is incredibly bad.  A one-element array is an array even though the comment suggests otherwise.

I've never seen anybody try to enforce "is an array" this way.  The array syntax is largely syntactic sugar (`a[2]` gives the same result as `2[a]`: i.e., the third element in `a` (**NOTE** [this is an interesting and valid syntax but usually a very bad form to use](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/arraysaspointers2.html) because you're going to confuse programmers for no reason)).

Because the array syntax is largely syntactic sugar, switching to a pointer makes sense as well.  But if you're going to do that, then going with `new[]` makes more sense (because you get your constructors called for free), and going with `std::vector` makes even more sense (because you don't have to remember to call `delete[]` every place the array goes out of scope due to return, break, the end of statement, throwing an exception, etc.).